# Setting up AngularJS template with API javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, api

I am new to AngularJS and want to convert my current website to AngularJS. Below is a section of my webpage that shows meetings pulled from Google calendar. I am using the API to do this. My questions is how would I convert the HTML/Javascript to an AngularJS template? Do I just use a controller and dump all the javascript in it?

Currently my HTML shows the first two results in my calendar list.

**This is my HTML:**

```
<section class="sub-box meetings-box">
    <div class="meetings-section">
        <span class="meeting-h1">NEXT MEETING</span>
        <div class="next-meetings-section">
            <div class="meeting-info meeting-time next-meeting-time-start"></div>
            <div class="meeting-info meeting-time next-meeting-time-end"></div>
            <div class="meeting-info next-meeting-title"></div>
            <div class="meeting-info next-meeting-location"></div>
        </div>

        <span class="meeting-h2">UPCOMING MEETINGS</span>
        <div class="upcoming-meetings-section">
        <div class="meeting-info meeting-time second-meeting-time-start"></div> 
        <div class="meeting-info meeting-time second-meeting-time-end"></div>
        <div class="meeting-info second-meeting-title"></div>
        <div class="meeting-info second-meeting-location"></div>
    </div>

</section>
```

**This is part of my Javascript that shows the callback response API**

```
    request.then(function(callbackResponse) {
    var entries = callbackResponse.result.items; //returns an array entries

      //get meeting info
      var nextMeeting = entries[0];
      var nextMeetingTimeStart = nextMeeting.start;
      var nextMeetingTimeEnd = nextMeeting.end;
      var nextMeetingTitle = nextMeeting.summary;
      var nextMeetingLocation = nextMeeting.location;

      var secondMeeting = entries[1];
      var secondMeetingTimeStart = secondMeeting.start;
      var secondMeetingTimeEnd = secondMeeting.end;
      var secondMeetingTitle = secondMeeting.summary;
      var secondMeetingLocation = secondMeeting.location;


  //formatting info
  for (var x in nextMeetingTimeStart && nextMeetingTimeEnd &&   
  secondMeetingTimeStart && secondMeetingTimeEnd) {
    var nextMeetingStart = nextMeetingTimeStart[x];
    var nextMeetingEnd = nextMeetingTimeEnd[x];

    var secondMeetingStart = secondMeetingTimeStart[x];
    var secondMeetingEnd = secondMeetingTimeEnd[x];

    var nextMeetingStartFormat = new Date(nextMeetingStart).toString('hh:mm tt');
    var nextMeetingEndFormat = new Date(nextMeetingEnd).toString('hh:mm tt');

    var secondMeetingStartFormat = new Date(secondMeetingStart).toString('hh:mm tt');
    var secondMeetingEndFormat = new Date(secondMeetingEnd).toString('hh:mm tt');

    $('.next-meetings-section').find('.next-meeting-time-start').text(nextMeetingStartFormat+'-');
    $('.next-meetings-section').find('.next-meeting-time-end').text(nextMeetingEndFormat);

    $('.upcoming-meetings-section').find('.second-meeting-time-start').text(secondMeetingStartFormat+'-');
    $('.upcoming-meetings-section').find('.second-meeting-time-end').text(secondMeetingEndFormat);
  }

  $('.next-meetings-section').find('.next-meeting-title').text(nextMeetingTitle);
  $('.next-meetings-section').find('.next-meeting-location').text(nextMeetingLocation);

  $('.upcoming-meetings-section').find('.second-meeting-title').text(secondMeetingTitle);
  $('.upcoming-meetings-section').find('.second-meeting-location').text(secondMeetingLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Angular you would want to use a `directive` for DOM Manipulation, a `factory` (there are other options but this is a good starting place) for http calls and to store data. The `controller` should be concerned with providing scope for the view.

Angular Documentation:

[controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

[directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

[providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) - factories are included here.

You may want to spend a few hours going through a tutorial or two before refactoring into Angular. [Code School has a good one for free.](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js)

Edit-

Looking at your code you would want to take care of the server response inside a `factory` - create properties on your factory for `nextMeeting` and `secondMeeting`, and have them set to your server response data each time you get a server response back with the data.

Inject your `factory` into a `controller`, then in your controller you can have properties your view will use like: `nextMeetingStart`, `nextMeetingEnd`, etc. The value of these properties can be functions that use the values on your factory's `nextMeeting` and `secondMeeting` properties to set their appropriate return values.

Then you can just reference those properties in your view. The values displayed in the view will update whenever the `factory` receives new data from the server.

Comment: Thanks! I actually just finished code school's course on Angular, but the examples that are used are with arrays of data. And the code that I am trying to convert are not in arrays.

Comment: Updated my answer with a general plan that would work with your code.

Comment: Thanks for you help so far. Can you help me get started with this bit of information I have starting my API request:
var clientId = '727304281402-2r6jn1l2jutllr07nc5ngba9omfqjand.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var apiKey = 'AIzaSyDk7clYywa4fx8t6lYOs4C20GfxK6MAQEE';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

I call handleClientLoad() in my html on load...

function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
  window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
}
function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
}